# Finding x intercept in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to find the x intercept of a parabola of a plot using

```
x0 = interp1(y,x,0)
```

However because my parabola starts at the origin it returns 0.

How do I find the x intercept that lies away from the origin? At the moment I am estimating by eye-ball.

Code for the plot:

```
global k g

g = 10;
v0 = 150;
theta = pi/4;
m = 1;
k = 0.001;

tspan = [0 22];

IC = [0; v0*cos(theta); 0; v0*sin(theta)];
[t, oput] = ode45(@dataODE, tspan, IC);

x = oput(:,1);
vx = oput(:,2);
y = oput(:,3);
vy = oput(:,4);

figure(1); clf;
plot(x,y)
```

where

```
function [p] = dataODE( t, x)

global k g

p = zeros(4,1);
p(1) = x(2);
p(2) = -k*sqrt(x(2)^2 + x(4)^2)* x(2);
p(3) = x(4);
p(4) = -g -k*sqrt(x(2)^2 + x(4)^2)* x(4);
```

Comment: If you have the equation for your parabola it would be much less complicated to solve it for `y` and set it equal to zero to find `x`...

Comment: @excaza I don't have a strict equation for my parabola (I am plotting the trajectory of a projectile)

Comment: btw don't use `global k g` use anonymous functions instead so `function [p] = dataODE(t, x, k, g)` and then call it like this `[t, oput] = ode45(@(t, x)dataODE(t,x,k,g), tspan, IC);` and remove both your `global` lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just restrict `x` and `y` to only contain the one intercept:

```
x0 = interp1(y(a:b),x(a:b),0)
```

but how do you find `a` and `b`? One way would be to just use the points before and after `y` crosses zero (on the way down):

```
a = find(diff(y > 0) == -1)
b = a+1
```